# I have code that works, with picture uploaded from gimp. But image created with gd not

Tags: php, png, gd

My problem is this, I want to create image thats combination of 3 image, first is yellow background, then I use PHP and GD to write some text on it, text is black, so I made it transparent in next step, then I want to put that picture over background picture, so text has texture on it. It works fine, if I upload PNG from my computer created in Gimp, but picture created with gd has transparency on it but result is again yellow background with black letters.

how it should be
[good result](http://novo.pulafilmfestival.hr/components/com_plakat/views/plakatis/tmpl/right.png)

what I get now from code:
[enter link description here](http://novo.pulafilmfestival.hr/components/com_plakat/views/plakatis/tmpl/wrong.png)

how it gets now with image created from gd

```
    <?php


     header('Content-Type: image/png');

    $title = "PULEŽANI";
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, 320);



    //$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, 320);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $crna = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $black = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    $yellow = imagecolorallocate($im, 251, 189, 8);
    // kreiram kvadrat sa žutom pozadinom
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $yellow);


    $font = "/AlrightSans-Ultra-v3.ttf";




    //dodajem text na žutu pozadinu
    imagettftext($im, 122, 0, 40, 160, $crna, $font, $title);
    //kreiram sliku crni tekst na žutoj pozadini
    imagepng($im, 'sl.png');
    imagedestroy($im);

    //ovaj dio bi trebao napraviti da crna slova postanu prozirna

    $image =  imagecreatefrompng('sl.png');

    $odabirprozirne = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0,127);
    imagealphablending($image, true);

    imagecolortransparent($image,$odabirprozirne);

    imagepng($image, 'sl114.png');
    imagedestroy($image);

    /* dodaj zvijezde odispod */
    $image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('TexturaZvijezde.png');
    $image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('sl114.png');
    imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
    imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1200, 120);
    imagepng($image_1);
    imagedestroy($image_1);
```

Comment: Are you wanting it an Image to be downloadable? If not you can put the transparent image over a div tag that has a background image

Comment: yes, it should go in gallery after approval....

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but according to the manual for [imagesavealpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) function,

> You have to unset alphablending (imagealphablending($im, false)), to use it.

Example:

```
// Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag
imagealphablending($png, false);
imagesavealpha($png, true);
```

Comment: I did try, but result is picture without transparency. I do get transparent picture with code above, but imagecopy result is wrong.